# Symfony 1.4 don't load sfFormExtraPlugin on production server

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

I have a site built in symfony 1.4. In the develop machine everything works ok, but when upload to production machine, plugins stop to load.
This is my project conf:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/public_html');   
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfFormExtraPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrineGuardPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('bootstrapAdminThemePlugin');
  }
}
```

I can see the js files loaded, for example: tiny_mce.js. But my textarea does not become text editor. Same thing with dates and autocompletes.
I have the same code in both servers.
Please any help?
Thank you.

Comment: something noted, it just with one module. But no javascript errors, so I'm blind!!

Comment: I found another thing, it look like my form class is not loaded. I made changes like unset fields and nothing happen, the view still show the form without errors. I'm really unconcerned about this.

Comment: What are the differences between your dev box and prod box? (OS, PHP version, etc). Did you check the Symfony logs and php error logs for any information?

Comment: Yes, no errors. Difference between machines are only OS version, not php neither apache.

Comment: But both are Linux? Or Linux and Windows?

Comment: 1. Backup all your production Data, symfony source code, webs, pictures, database schema and data. Make a complete security copy that you can restore later in case of disaster.
2. Try clearing the symfony cache with symfony cc. 3. You may also edit the source code of sfFormExtraPlugin, and add some: echo "test"; at the beginning of the functions too see where its hanging, or even debug it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual issue ? symfony Modules or JS files not loaded ?

Maybe you forgot to publish the plugin assets ?

Have you tried

```
php symfony plugin:publish-assets
```